# Quotient $SO(3)/SO(2)$

Tags: rotations, topological-groups, quotient-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

To identify an element of $SO(3)$, i.e. a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we must specify a direction in space, i.e. a straight line through the origin, and a rotation angle.

To specify an element of $SO(2)$ we just need the rotation angle.

Then one might argue that the quotient $SO(3)/SO(2)$ corresponds to the space of directions in $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. a projective space. But this is not the case: the quotient is actually $S^2$, the spherical surface.

Why must we not identify antipodal points of $S^2$? Do they not correspond to the same direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption that “To identify an element of $SO(3)$ […] we must specify a direction in space, i.e. a straight line through the origin, and a rotation angle” is not correct. To see why, consider, say, the straight line $\Bbb R(0,0,1)$ and the angle $\frac\pi2$. Does this describe an element of $SO(3)$? No; it applies to *two* elements of $SO(3)$, since there are two distinct rotations with angle $\frac\pi2$ around that line. So, it is indeed natural that $SO(3)/SO(2)$ can be seen as $S^2$.

Comment: Do you mean that we can rotate counter-clockwise or clockwise?

Comment: Then we could identify one point of $S^2$ with the clockwise rotations, and its antipodal with the counter-clockwise ones. This makes sense to me, if it is indeed correct.

Comment: Yes, we can rotate in both ways.

Comment: But if I say that the rotation angle must be between $0$ and $2\pi$, then there is only one rotation by $\pi/2$, not two

Comment: Let $B$ be the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Then the rotation whose matrix with respect to $B$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$is a rotation of angle $\frac\pi2$ around $\Bbb R(0,0,1)$. But if I consider now the basis$$B'=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,-1)\}$$instead, then the rotation whose matrix with respect to $B'$ is the same as above is another rotation of angle $\frac\pi2$ around $\Bbb R(0,0,1)$. So, there are indeed **two** such (distinct) rotations.

Comment: @thedude A rotation by $-\pi/2$ from one perspective is a rotation by $+\pi/2$ from the opposite perspective. Indeed, there is way to label which rotation is "clockwise" vs "counterclockwise," since that depends on how you're looking at a rotation. Imagine drawing a semicircular arrow on a transparent marker board - you and someone on the other side of the glass panel will be looking at the same rotation but disagreeing on if it's clockwise or counterclockwise.